# Problema al evaluar si un punto pertenece a un Poligono utilizando el tipo de Datos GEOMETRY - SQL SERVER 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenos días,

Estoy armando un procedimiento en T-SQL para que detecte si un punto pertenece a un poligono de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al estar poniendo un punto exacto que esta en el poligono, el metodo STContains debería devolverme un 1 (Pertenece) y me está devolviendo un 0 (No pertenece a un poligono).

Que estoy haciendo mal? 
Es correcta la forma en que estoy manipulando estos tipos de datos y sus métodos?
Muchas gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que el problema aquí es de interpretación del funcionamiento de [`STContains`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stcontains-geometry-data-type), si leemos la documentación:

> Returns 1 if a geometry instance completely contains another geometry
>   instance. Returns 0 if it does not.

Lo importante es "completely contains", y aquí me pregunto, un punto del vértice de un polígono ¿está completamente contenido en el mismo? Entiendo que no y podemos verificarlo fácilmente:

```
DECLARE @G1 GEOMETRY
DECLARE @G2 GEOMETRY

SELECT  @G1 = GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((175 150, 20 40, 50 60, 125 100, 175 150))', 0),
    @G2 = GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText('POINT (174 149)', 0)

SELECT  @G1.STContains(GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText('POINT (175 150)', 0))  AS 'P1',
    @G1.STContains(GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText('POINT (20 40)', 0))    AS 'P2',
    @G1.STContains(GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText('POINT (50 60)', 0))    AS 'P3',
    @G1.STContains(GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText('POINT (125 100)', 0))  AS 'P4'
```

La Salida:

```
+----+----+----+----+
| P1 | P2 | P3 | P4 |
+----+----+----+----+
| 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  |
+----+----+----+----+
```

Vemos que ninguno de los puntos vértice del polígono están contenidos completamente en el. Lo que si puedes es determinar la intersección de un punto con el polígono, usando [`STIntersects()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stintersects-geometry-data-type):

```
SELECT  @G1.STIntersects(GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText('POINT (175 150)', 0))    AS 'P1',
    @G1.STIntersects(GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText('POINT (20 40)', 0))      AS 'P2',
    @G1.STIntersects(GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText('POINT (50 60)', 0))      AS 'P3',
    @G1.STIntersects(GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText('POINT (125 100)', 0))    AS 'P4'
```

La salida:

```
+----+----+----+----+
| P1 | P2 | P3 | P4 |
+----+----+----+----+
| 1  | 1  | 1  | 1  |
+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Patricio. Utilizando los dos métodos STContains() para ver si un punto pertenece a un Poligono y STIntersects() para ver si un punto pertenece al vértice o arista del poligono, quedo cubierto todo el poligono.

Comment: No necesitas ambos,  `STIntersects()` cubre ambos casos. Saludos

Comment: Perfecto! Muchas Gracias Patricio!